# conditional expectation onto discrete MASA

Tags: operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

In the above screnshot, $X$ is a MASA in $L(H)$ and $Z\in L(H)$. I tried to prove (3.1) and met with a question.

When we take $Z =\begin{pmatrix}A & B\\C & D\end{pmatrix}
$, where $A\in L(H_d), B\in L(H_c,H_d), C\in L(H_d,H_c), D\in L(H_c)$.
Then we have $E_{X}(Z)=\begin{pmatrix}E_{D}(A) & 0\\0 & E_C(D)\end{pmatrix}$.

My question: what is the relationship between $E_{X}(Z)$ and $E_{D}(Z_{H_d})$? Or does there exist relationships between $E_D(A)$ and $E_{D}(Z_{H_d})$?

Since $H_d$ is not an invariant subspace for $Z$, so the $Z_{H_d}\in L(H_d,H)$, and I cannot  express the $Z_{H_d}$ in terms of the 2 by 2 matrix with operator entries.

Comment: What do you mean by a "masa" ? A mass ?

Comment: masa means "maximal abelian$*$-subalgebra of a von Neumann algebra"

Comment: Thanks. Hard to guess. I thought it is a spanish word... I advise you to use capital letters : MASA.

Comment: @JeanMarie: the use, in lowercase and without periods, of the term "masa" 
 is completely standard in the von Neumann algebra literature.

Comment: @mathbeginner: what's $Z_{H_d}$?

Comment: @Martin Argerami，I guess it means that $Z$ restricted to the closed subspace $H_d$.

Comment: But $H_d$ is not necessarily invariant for $Z$. And if you consider the restriction of $Z$ to $H_d$ you get an operator $H_d\to H$ and then it is not clear how to apply $E_D$ to it.

Comment: Yes. This is the place where troubled me.

Comment: In that paper, the authors don't give the notation of $Z_{Hd}$

Comment: The Proposition is sated as following: If $X$ is a masa in $L(H)$ and $Z\in L(H)$, then $W_e(E_X(Z))\subset W_e(Z)$, where $E_X() $ denotes the conditional expectation from $L(H)$ to $X$.

Comment: That's why I asked. The only interpretation I can think for $Z_{H_d}$ is what you called $A$.

Comment: But according to the decomposition, $H_d$ may not be an invariant subspcae for $Z$.

Comment: I think the conlusion is true when $H_d$ is an invariant subspace for $Z$.